# how to get a blank canvas on which I can write using stylus

Tags: java, android, canvas

[image: This is what I am looking for]

I am creating a service application where in the person who uses the service fills his data and signs it
Now I want to create a blank page where I can take the signature of the client on the TAB itself. So please help to do this.How can I implement it.
I have refereed to this http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Creating.html link but some how I am not able to work with it.
Please help.Thanks

Comment: you can have a view and override on draw and draw freehand. check fingerpaaint example in the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using GestureOverlayView. Example in the links: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-gestureoverlayview-to-capture-a-quick-signature-or-drawing/

Specifically, create a GestureOverlayView in your layout xml file, then in your Activity class capture the gesture and save it as bitmap image.

Go through the developer API if you want to have specific function for your page, especially for events like Gesturing or Gesture Finish : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html

Hope that helps